# django filter by date range from a foreign key

Tags: django, django-filter

I have models defined like the following:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

I am trying to filter out some entries based on dates as follows:

```
gl = OrderDetail.objects.filter(order.order_date__range=('2015-02-02','2015-03-10'))
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
File "<console>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django uses the `__` syntax to replace the `.` in filter queries.

```
gl = OrderDetail.objects.filter(order__order_date__range=('2015-02-02','2015-03-10'))
```